# What does 0x1 in Golang mean?

Tags: go, memory, binary, byte

I'm trying to understand this piece of code for returning how many zeroes a byte array is prefixed with but I'm not sure what 0x1 is. Google search isn't helpful, but I'm assuming `0x1` is returning the first bit? What are these called?

Also, I know this is a separate question but I don't think it warrants a new thread: I don't quite understand why we're nesting a loop here, bit shifting, and subtracting j from 7. Is this how the byte is transformed into binary?

```
IdLength := 32
func PrefixLen(count [IdLength]byte) int {
    for i := 0; i < IdLength; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 8; j++ {
            if (count[i]>>uint8(7-j))&0x1 != 0 {
                return i*8 + j
            }
        }
    }
    return IdLength*8 - 1
}
```

Comment: This is a integer literal in hex. E.g. 0x10 == 16. Writing 0x1 is just a fancy way to write 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x1` is just the hexadecimal notation of number `1`. You `&` some integer with `0x1` to get its least significant (rightmost) bit. You write `0x1` instead of `1` when using a bit mask because it's easier to convert from base 16 than from base 10 to base 2.

For the second question, what `func PrefixLen` does is finding the number of consecutive zeroes on the beginning of `count`. The outer loop does one byte each time, and the inner loop deals with separate bits: when j=0 it shifts 7 to the right thus getting the first bit from left, when j=1 it shifts 6 getting the second bit, and so on. When a bit of `1` is encountered it returns the count of bits already checked.